# ./configure: bdw-gc not found when building Inkscape from source

Tags: configure

What is the common way to investigate on this issue that appears during `./configure`?

```
configure: error: Package requirements (bdw-gc      >= 7.1
                  cairo       >= 1.10
                  cairomm-1.0 >= 1.9.8
                  glib-2.0    >= 2.28
                  glibmm-2.4  >= 2.28
                  giomm-2.4
                  gsl
                  gthread-2.0 >= 2.0
                  libpng      >= 1.2
                  libxml-2.0  >= 2.6.11
                  libxslt     >= 1.0.15
                  pango       >= 1.24
                  pangoft2    >= 1.24
                  sigc++-2.0  >= 2.0.12
                  ) were not met:

No package 'bdw-gc' found
```

I just downloaded and built `bdw-gc` from https://github.com/ivmai/bdwgc/

I guess the problem is maybe because `bdw-gc` was installed into `/usr/local/bin`, not `/usr/local`

I tried this:

```
LDFLAGS=-L/usr/local/lib LIBS=-lgc ./configure
```

Answer (score 8):

`bdw-gc` refers to the  [Boehm-Demers-Weiser garbage collector for C and C++](http://www.hboehm.info/gc/). You need to install the `gc-devel` or `libgc-dev` package.

In openSUSE:

```
zypper install gc-devel
```

In Fedora:

```
yum install gc-devel
```

In Ubuntu:

```
apt-get install libgc-dev
```

---

Here's more information:

```
$ yum search boehm
======================= Description & URL Matched: boehm =======================
gc.x86_64 : A garbage collector for C and C++
gc.i686 : A garbage collector for C and C++
============================== URL Matched: boehm ==============================
gc-devel.i686 : Libraries and header files for gc development
gc-devel.x86_64 : Libraries and header files for gc development
...
```

And:

```
$ apt-cache search boehm
libgc-dev - conservative garbage collector for C (development)
libgc1c2 - conservative garbage collector for C and C++
...
```

Comment: Welcome to Super User. A common mistake new users make is to answer without details of how to actually resolves the issue. Answers should be detailed and include references, as needed. Please take a few minutes to edit your answer to include details of why your answer is valid. If you need some help, read [How do I write a good answer?](//superuser.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thanks, working for my on Inkscape 1.1